# How to change theme of particular view in Android

Tags: android, view, styles, themes

my app uses classic (dark) holo theme. While using this theme, EditTexts are white looking, of course. However I have small ViewGroup container with some EditTexts which has white background. They have obviously bad visibility so I want to use Holo.Light just for the ViewGroup in order to have these EditTexts black.

I tried to use this style for every EditText in the ViewGroup:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:saveEnabled="false"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.EditText" />
```

And it behaves strange since only hint color was set to "dark looking" EditText. For example drawable is still white.

Please can you write me how to change theme for one particular view ? So I can still use classic Holo for app, but change only some Views to Holo.Light.

Comment: Lollipop now allows this: https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year later but I have also been looking for an answer. In the base layout, put the following:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme2"
```

To apply the style just to that view.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new a theme that inherits from the light holo theme instead of the dark one and try setting that as the theme of the parent view.

```
app:theme="@style/YourCustomTheme"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't get it. What is namespace "app" because if I use it in ViewGroup which contains that EditText it says that namespace 'app' is not bound. And if I use android:theme=... instead, it does not work (no effect).